# Animate images in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have 5 images that is to be displayed at the bottom of my screen.
Now what i want is the images to appear one after the other and in a infinite loop type display (i.e After the 5th Image the 1st image should appear). This should go on as long as the user is on this page.

I tried Carousel, but after the 5th image, an auto rewind action takes place and the 1st image is loaded(Horrible).

How do i achieve the same using simple animation ?

Comment: `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
            {
                SlidePosition++;
    if (SlidePosition == Sponsors.Count) SlidePosition = 0; 
    CarouselZoos.Position = SlidePosition;
                return true; 
   });` This rewinds the image back to the 1st image after the 5th image which is bad user exp.

Comment: This is going to rewind Carousel and that is not what you want, is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carousel View Auto Sliding in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984828/carousel-view-auto-sliding-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: This is because it animates the movement between the image indexes, so when it goes to index 0, from index 4 it animates it backwards. I think to change this behavior you would need to create a custom carousel that derives from the base class. Alternatively you could make your own using a combination of animations and Image controls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like this:

```
string[] image = { "image1","another","third","oneMore","lastImage"};
int index = 0;

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () => 
{
    if(index >= (image.Length - 1))
        index = 0;
    else
        index++;
    imgView.FadeTo(0.1, 250, Easing.Linear);
    imgView.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(image[index]);
    imgView.FadeTo(1, 250, Easing.Linear);

    return true;
});
```

Use a simple Image instead of the CarouselView. Maybe you'll need surround the actions over imgView with a "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread". Check it out.